# Smeared dots with Denoise 2.79

Tags: rendering, denoise

I'm new to this world. I was rendering a test scene, to see differences of using the Denoise feature. Anyone know why the Denoise version (bottom image) has these weird smeared dots in them?

[image]

Comment: That's what denoise does, what were you expecting to see? It blurs noise away, and tries to be "smart" about it but your base image is just too noisy, or your settings are too aggressive so you get bad denoising artifacts.

Comment: You need to use more samples to have a clean image. Denoise is not a substitute for more samples...Start with the default options for denoise and find the number of samples that will give you a clean image. Maybe then fine tune the settings for denoise. Agressive denoising will only result in smearing, blocking and blurred images or other artifacts.

Comment: Cycles can produce some amazing results, but it can also be temperamental and go wildly wrong. That’s why we have so many ways of tweaking its output (e.g. clamp direct/indirect, filtering in the compositor), and why denoise was added as yet one more. None of them is perfect: each one works well in some situations, not so well in others. Sometimes you need a combination; other times more radical solutions are called for, like cheating on your material settings.